# iOS 9: How to update the attributed content in a UITextView with a Custom NSTextStorage

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, ios9, nstextstorage

I'm using an `UITextView` to display an attributed string with custom attributes. For this reason I decided to implement my own `NSTextStorage`, that way after each processing I can insert my custom attributes.

Whenever I need to display the `UITextView` I used to set its text like this:

`textView.attributedText = mutableText`

However by using my new `NSTextStorage` it seems that updating the `attributedText` has no effect on the UITextView, it just shows the placeholder text that it was created with.

How can I connect the `attributedText` property of the `UITextView` to the attributedString that is stored in the `NSTextStorage`? What methods do I need to override on both objects for this to be possible?